# C++ Visual Studio class error identifier string is undefined

Tags: c++

I made a class. the header file is :

```
   #pragma once
#include <string>
class Player
{
public:
    Player();
private:
};
```

and the cpp file is :

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
Player::Player()
{
}
```

When I define a string in the header file and add an argument to the Player function in the header file everything works fine

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Player
{
public:
    Player(string name);
private:
    string _name;
};
```

but when I add the same argument to the Player function in the cpp file

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
Player::Player(string name)
{
}
```

I get an error: identifier "string" is undefined and I get the same error in the header file as well so it effects that too. I tried including string in the cpp file in hopes of solving the problem but it did not work. I'm really desperate for a solution, guys.

Comment: It's missing the namespace before `string`. Did you try `std::string`? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: I doubt that the header change works as you say it does!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All STL types, algorithms etc are declared inside `std` namespace.

To make your code compile, `string` type should also specify the namespace as:

```
Player(std::string name);  /* Most recommended */
```

or

```
using namespace std;
Player(string name);  /* Least recommended, as it will pollute the available symbols */
```

or

```
using std::string;
Player(string name);
```

Comment: _`using namespace std;`_ Shudder!

Comment: @momomo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list NOT tutorials!!